# Visual basic scripting: is there a way to stop a Exec if it takes longer then I need

Tags: vbscript

So to be honest i am trying to create a ping scan tool to tell me what devices are online using a visual basic script. I am not sure how to stop the ping command if it runs longer then .25-.5 seconds(basically if there is no response). The end goal is to create a script that scans all 255 ip addresses in a range and let me know which ones are alive and display them in a document as fast as possible. My current script is slow and i would like to skip a full ping of an ip address if it doesn't receive a response asap. I know there is a million and one ways to do this but for my own entertainment puposes i want to create my own. Bonus: I plan to display that data live at some point and would appreciate some assistance with that as well. DON'T DO EVERYTHING FOR ME. I am learning this on my own and someone doing this for me has no benefit to me. I only want to be pointed in the right direction. This is a self assigned project.

```
 Dim x, prompt, title, DefaultValue ' Declare 
prompt = "Please enter the first 3 octets of the Ip range you wish to scan in the format    of XXX.XXX.XXX."
 title = "Quick ping scan"
 DefaultValue = "192.168.1."
UserEntry = InputBox(prompt, title, DefaultValue)
pingscan = "ping -n 1 "
Set start = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
If (UserEntry = "") Then
prompt = "Please enter a valid ip address"
title = "Quick ping scan"
UserEntry = InputBox(prompt, title, DefaultValue)
Else
End If
for x = 1 to 255
Set finalvalue = (start.Exec("ping -n 1 "&UserEntry &x))
Set Output = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(".\PS_results.txt",8,true)
strOutput = finalvalue.StdOut.ReadAll
If ((InStr(1, strOutput, "bytes=32")) = "71") Then
Output.WriteLine strOutput
Else 
End If
Output.close
Next
result = MsgBox ("Ping Scan is finished. Do you want to open the file?",vbYesNo+vbInformation, "")
If(result="6") Then
    start.Exec("notepad .\PS_results.txt")
ElseIf(result="7") Then
    WScript.Echo "Ping Scan is complete"
    End If
```

Comment: you can go for one more thread which checks the time how long script has been running. Refer to this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610686/vbscript-threading

Comment: Isn't `.255` reserved broadcast address shouldn't it be `for x = 1 to 254`? I did something similar to this years ago that used a database to lookup predefined subnets and go scan each one, when it found a host that could support WMI it would inject another vbs script on to the host and execute it remotely to populate the database with information about the host, it also run some unattended installs. This was before the days of group policy.

Comment: Touche Sir. Better yet i noticed that it check for 71 characters in only. So as soon as i change the ip address to like 10.44.3. it wont log anything untill the ip addresses reach 100. What is an easy way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a command prompt command that does it. The same objects are available in vbs and I'll give you a sample thing on how to access objects.

```
wmic /node:@"c:\SomeFileFilledWithComputernamesWithoutSlashesOrIPAddresses.txt /failfast:on computersystem get caption /format:list >serversonline.txt
```

Try /Format: List, Table, CSV, Hform (html list), and HTable. Make the output an htm file if using h formats.

/failfast:on means if it doesn't answer it doesn't wait for it (after all computers normally answer quickly).

/node do something like

```
serenity
trigger
127.0.0.1
129.6.87.23
```

This is how to access wmi objects in vbs (but command prompt is easier).

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.Caption
Next
```

The \\.\, the dot is the computer name. . means local computer. To do 127.0.0.1

```
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\127.0.0.1\root\cimv2")
```

Comment: It occurs to me that I use NET VIEW command to build the server list. This lists servers turned on. So maybe NET VIEW will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will try these out and report back. Thank you again any outside opions and assistance are greatly appreciated.